# Validate an integer and integer range in java

Tags: java

I've been working on this simple issue for hours and not getting anywhere.  I'm trying to validate that a number inputted into my program is between 1 and 12. I've tried several kinds of loops but get various errors and problems which I've detailed in the comments at the top of the sample code:

```
//This gives me an error saying that the local variable deptMonth may not have
//been initialized

boolean monthCorrect;
int deptMonth;
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); 

    do
    {
        System.out.print("Please input the month (1-12): ");
        if (input.hasNextInt())
        {
            if ((input.nextInt()) <= 12 && (input.nextInt()) >=1)
            {
                deptMonth = input.nextInt();
                monthCorrect = true;
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("I don't understand try again.");
                monthCorrect = false;
                input.next();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("I don't understand try again.");
            monthCorrect = false;
            input.next();
        }

    }while (!(monthCorrect));
```

Is there an easier and correct way to do this?

Thank you.

Comment: `((input.nextInt()) <= 12 && (input.nextInt()) >=1)` - don't do this.  If you call `nextInt()` twice, your program will try to read two separate numbers.  Call it once and assign it to a variable.

Answer (score 0):

You're calling the method `nextInt` repeatedly. Isn't that going to eat up multiple input tokens? Try this: call `nextInt` just once and assign that to a variable, let's call it `foo`. Then test `foo` to see if it is in the correct range, and if so, assign `foo` to `deptMonth`.

Answer (score -1):

Like Robert said, you need to assign the
    input.nextInt()
to a variable inside of the do loop. Calling this method multiple times results in you having to enter a value multiple times. So, in order for your code to work, it should like more like this:

```
boolean monthCorrect;
int deptMonth;
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); 

do
{
    System.out.print("Please input the month (1-12): ");
    if (input.hasNextInt())
    {
        int tmp = input.nextInt();
        if ((tmp) <= 12 && (tmp) >=1)
        {
            deptMonth = tmp;
            monthCorrect = true;
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("I don't understand try again.");
            monthCorrect = false;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("I don't understand try again.");
        monthCorrect = false;
    }

}while (!(monthCorrect));
```

Also, I don't know if you are continuing input or not, but it is good practice to close the Scanner once you are done with it, to prevent memory issues and such.

So,

```
if ((tmp) <= 12 && (tmp) >=1)
        {
            deptMonth = tmp;
            monthCorrect = true;
        }
```

Should look like:

```
if ((tmp) <= 12 && (tmp) >=1)
        {
            deptMonth = tmp;
            monthCorrect = true;
            input.close();//This keeps everything tidy! Also eclipse should give you a warning message if you forget to include it!
        }
```

Comment: I think you should test this in the case where the user enters something that isn't a number.  It looks to me like you'll get trapped in an endless loop.

Comment: Actually, I used input.nextInt(), so it would block until an INTEGER was entered. But thanks for the -1 buddy, real nice.